# unable to print string after reversing in C

Tags: c, string

I have written below program to reverse the string, but it is not printed after reversal.
What could be the issue?

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>

main()
{
    char p[] = "krishna";
    
    strrv(p);
    printf("%s", p);    // -----> nothing prints here
}

void strrv(char p[])
{
    int l = strlen(p);
    int i=0;
    char tmp;
    
    
    while(i<l)
    {
        tmp = p[i];
        p[i] = p[l];
        p[l] = tmp;
        
        i++;
        l--;
    }
}
```

Comment: First of all, what does your text-book say about declaring functions before calling them? Secondly, what do your text-book say about string, more precisely about how they are *null-terminated*? And do your function reverse that null-terminator as well?

Comment: And you really should take this as an opportunity to learn two things: Building with extra warnings, and treating any and all warnings the compiler generates as actual errors that *must* be fixed; And how to *debug* your code, for example by using a debugger to step through your code statement by statement while monitoring variables and their values.

Comment: There are tons of code examples for how to reverse a string. Have you looked at one of those?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the first loop iteration `p[l]` will refer to the terminating `\0` of `p` which is then assigned to `p[0]` and that in turn that makes `p` an empty string.  The fix is to initialize `l` to `strlen(p) - 1` instead of `strlen(p)`:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void strrv(char p[]) {
    for(int i = 0, l = strlen(p) - 1; i < l; i++, l--) {
        char tmp = p[i];
        p[i] = p[l];
        p[l] = tmp;
    }
}

int main() {
    char p[] = "krishna";
    strrv(p);
    printf("%s", p);
    return 0;
}
```